# Async.times error when deploying Node.js app to heroku (repeated loop)

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, async.js, for-in-loop

I have a web app that uses JavaScript, jQuery, and `async.times` (among other components) to get a list of artists and songs from the Spotify API and insert them into the page in order. On my local Node.js server, this functionality works perfectly. However, upon deploying to Heroku, there seems to be an error involving the asynchronous function, because it seems to run the loop twice and append the list two times.

This is the code that appends the data to the page:

```
var counter = 0;
      for (var id in relatedArtists) {
        relatedArtists[counter] = relatedArtists[id];
        delete relatedArtists[id];
        counter++;
      }
async.times(counter, function(n, next) {
  console.log(n);
  console.log(relatedArtists[n].id);
  s.getArtistTopTracks(relatedArtists[n].id, "US", function (err, data2) {
    relatedArtists[n].song = data2.tracks[0].name; 
    relatedArtists[n].uri = data2.tracks[0].uri;
    $('#related-artist').append(
      '<p><strong>' + relatedArtists[n].name + '</strong> -- \"' +
      relatedArtists[n].song + '\"</p>'
    );
    next(null, relatedArtists[n].uri);       
  });
},
```

The deployed version is here: http://whatshouldilistentotoday.herokuapp.com/finalproject/

Heroku says that it shouldn't be a problem on their end, because they use a vanilla Node.js installation on ubuntu, but I can't figure out why `async.times` would run the proper number of times locally but not on their server.

Comment: You are probably going to need to include more source.  For example, how is counter getting set?

Comment: @Gary I edited the post to include how the counter is being set.

Comment: You are doing weird stuff. Where is `relatedArtists` initialised? Is it an array or an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating properties on an object in the loop that deletes all properties from that object.

This is *begging* for trouble. From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate):

> If new properties are added to the target object during enumeration, the newly added properties are not guaranteed to be processed in the active enumeration.

So just don't do that, it's completely implementation-dependent. I wouldn't be surprised if this goes into an infinite loop and hangs your server.

Just use two separate objects, for your own sanity. Apart from that, I don't see any reason to use these integer `counter` properties at all, just go for [`async.forEachOfSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreachofobj-iterator-callback) instead of that `.times` method.

Comment: Thank you, I will work on this and think about it further. Do you have an idea why this code would work on my local server despite its flaws? I guess heroku is just more strict about this.

Comment: What should the two separate objects be for? The relatedArtists and relatedArtists songs?

Comment: @YamiMedina: It might just be that you're using a different node version. Or `relatedArtits` was initialised differently *somehow* (there's actually a myriad of reasons)

Comment: @YamiMedina: The separate object should be `relatedArtistsByCounter`, in contrast to the `relatedArtists` by id. You should not use `delete` at all. Or, if you used that `counter` thingy only for the `async.times` iterations and not needed it for something else (I don't know?), you should just swap out your enumeration method.

Comment: Thank you! I created a new object called `relatedArtistsByCounter` to hold and delete `relatedArtists[id]` and other information through the loop, and now it prints to the DOM properly (one time each in proper order).